# what in asp.net instead of httpsessionlistener in java

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

> I am new to asp.net. I want to map the end user status,user is online or offline(here i considered offline due to direct PC shutdown case also).In java I use **httpsessionlistener**  but I don't understand what should I use in asp.net and how to map that user is offline ?? Please help me. Which method should I use?

Comment: What do you intend to do when the user's computer is turned off? That's a use case I haven't encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the Session_End event in Global.asax: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: How i can handel session_end when unexpected pc shutdown occures???? Please help thanx.

Comment: You can't. There is no way of running ASP.NET code when an end-user's machine shuts down unexpectedly, and I'd love to see what it was you did in Java. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't know exact thing in java but one java developer suggest me to use HttpSessionBindingListener for handling this situation in java. I want solution in asp.net.
My problem is when user comes online I mark him as online when he log out or close the browser i map that and make them offline ,But I am not able to map user is online or offline when unexpected pc shutdown occures at user/client side? still it shows user is online..can u please help me to handel this situation?